# How do I write a Ruby where clause with dates and array lookup?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause

```
local_appointment_records = ExternalAppointment.where(external_id: appointment_ids, deleted_by: nil, ('start_time BETWEEN ? AND ?',@date_from, @date_to) )
```

I want to do something like the above.
I first want to check if the model external id is in the array of appointment_ids, then make sure it is not soft deleted and then check if the record start time is between dates..
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use a SQL string to create that query. Just use a range:

```
local_appointment_records = ExternalAppointment.where(
  external_id: appointment_ids, 
  deleted_by: nil, 
  start_time: @date_from..@date_to
)
```

If you want to use a SQL string you want to chain the calls:

```
local_appointment_records = ExternalAppointment.where(
  external_id: appointment_ids, 
  deleted_by: nil
).where(
  'start_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to
)
```

Comment: On a side note - if `appointment_ids` is actually something fetched from the database you can actually pass an ActiveRecord::Relation and let ActiveRecord compose a subquery.